# How do I add a chart to firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

im currently creating an app where the user is suppose to click a couple of buttons and get a chart back. So far so good. But I want them to be able to save the chart in their profile so they can look at it whenever they want. I have no idea how to do it. I have played around with Auth but I just dont get it. I have googled to no avail. I have checked firebase website but im not sure what im looking for.

I tried repeating some of the steps for when it saves the account user and password.. but I dont know if im missing a specific set of syntax for this or I just dont know the proper command.

Does anyone know how to solve this or point in the right direction? Can it even be done?

I have been at it the whole day....

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is getting some downvotes because it's too vague - we don't really know what you're asking. What does "save the chart in their profile" mean? You should really first start with the [Firebase Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) guide to see how to Read and Write data. Then craft some code that writes the data you want (and reads it) and when you get stuck then post a question about that code. In the meantime consider clarifying what you're trying to do so we can lend a hand. Either way we need to see your code!

Answer (score 0):

A chart is simply a presentation of data. You add the data to firebase and then you can later retrieve that data to present in anyway you wish (as a chart in your case).

Take a look at this example that uses canvasjs to present data as a chart: https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/chart-index-data-label/

If you're following some steps but are running into an issue you have to be specific because without more detailed information it's anyone's guess what the issue is as to why it isn't working.

> but I dont know if im missing a specific set of syntax for this or I
> just dont know the proper command.

How do you know something is not working? What's the result and what's the expected result?

Your first step would be to get authentication working. You can follow this documentation to help you get setup using the web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

After that you want to use create a database that has a collection, say 'charts' where each document could have the 'uid' of the users.

Take a look at this step-by-step tutorial.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d-gIPGzmK4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB
It guides you through authentication as well as storing data. Once you get that setup, viewing your data as a chart would be a front-end presentational thing and depend on what you're using to display the data. If you're using reactjs, https://react-charts.js.org looks like a good option.

Comment: @Julius For clarification, you do not need authentication to read and write data to Firebase. You will need it at some point but not to get started; you can simply set your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#default_rules_locked_mode) to true instead of false and learn how to interact with the platform. This question is also marked as the Realtime Database so there are no collections and that tutorial does not apply. Maybe this answer can be updated with additional info.